# Custom readline autocompletion menu items in color

Tags: c, readline

I'm using readline to accept user input in my C program that implements a domain specific language (DSL). I have a custom completion function that correctly suggests keywords from the DSL for matching typed prefixes.

However, I'd like to display some of the matching choices in different colors. For example, typing `in` followed by <kbd>tab</kbd> produces the choices `inline` and `int` that match the prefix `in`:

```
prompt> declare foo as in[tab]
inline  int
prompt> declare foo as in
```

But I want, say, `int` in a different color.

I know readline has the capability to do this because it can complete filenames in colors based in their type, but there doesn't seem to be any way to color custom completions via the C API.

Is there a way to get custom completion suggestions in colors?

**Note**: I tried including the [ANSI color escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) into the menu choice strings returned to readline, but it incorporates those characters into the buffer and prints them literally, so that apparently doesn't work.

Comment: I guess thta of you control the offered suggestions you also control their display mode. If so, then you could use ASCII VT100 config change ?

Comment: @Jib I tried: it includes the escape sequences into the suggestions (not what I want) and also prints them literally, so it apparently doesn't work.

Comment: that's weird it does not work. Would you mind sharing how you did it? Escape sequence should be like \x1b[31m` for instance

Comment: @Jib I included `\33[32m\33[K` (to start printing in green) followed by the string followed by `\33[m` to stop printing in color.

Comment: @Jib If you look at readline source code, it sorts the completion strings returned to it. Having escape codes in there would mess up both the sorting and its max-length calculation. FYI, there is `rl_completion_display_matches_hook`, but then you have to take over the printing of the entire list which would be kind of a pain.

Comment: I get your point now, may be you can add this detail to your question..